# Firestore Security Rules: How should I test that a particular operation (e.g. get:) is completely disabled?

Tags: typescript, firebase, unit-testing, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

Is there any way to test that a security rule operation (e.g. `get:`, `delete:`) is completely disabled (ie. `false`)?

No matter how thorough my unit tests, technically I can't guarantee that a new security rule condition doesn't allow the operation.

For example, I'd like my unit test to ensure that the `delete` operation is completely disabled for a particular collection.

The test below correctly fails. However, how can I reliably guarantee with unit tests that there isn't an arbitrary security rule condition that would allow it?

```js
import "jest"
import * as firebase from "@firebase/rules-unit-testing"

const baseOptions = {projectId: 'my-project'}

function admin() {
  return firebase.initializeAdminApp(baseOptions).firestore()
}

function client(uid: string) {
  const options = Object.assign({uid: uid}, baseOptions)
  return firebase.initializeTestApp(options).firestore()
}

describe("/theCollection", () => {

  const collection = "theCollection";

  describe("delete:", () => {
    it("fails", async () => {
      // setup
      const uid = '123'
      const docId = 'abc'
      await admin().collection(collection).doc(docId).set({uid: uid})

      // test
      await firebase.assertFails(
        client(uid).collection(collection).doc(docId).delete(),
      )
      // ^--- this doesn't guarantee that deletes are disabled for everyone
    })
  })
})
```

#### Testing Libraries:

- [security rules emulator](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/test-rules-emulator)
- [@firebase/rules-unit-testing](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@firebase/rules-unit-testing)

Comment: You linked to the functions emulator, which won't help you at all with security rules.  Use the security rules emulator instead to write your tests. https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/test-rules-emulator

Comment: Ah sorry I linked the wrong one. I'm using the emulator that you linked

Comment: I suggest following that documentation.  If you have code that doesn't work the way you expect, you should share that and explain what's wrong.

Comment: I haven't found anything in the documentation or source code that addresses this. I added a sample test to clarify what I'm talking about

Answer (score 1):

Due to the nature of Firestore security rules, I believe you can't test if a specific operation is completely disabled.

Since you could always have a rule that allows a certain operation if a specific condition is met, I believe that the most you could do is to write tests for each Firestore rule with test cases that should work and others that shouldn't. This won't give you the certainty of knowing that there won't be another rule in the future that will change the behavior of the previous one, but at least, by writing tests for every rule you will have a more accurate picture of the situation.

AFAIK, this would be a viable approach given how Firestore rules work

Comment: Ok that's what I figured. I just submitted a feature request to expose rejection reasons from the emulator so that they can be tested.

Answer (score 0):

> how can I reliably guarantee with unit tests that there isn't an arbitrary security rule condition that would allow it?

You can't.  All you can do in test code is to propose specific test cases that are expected to pass or fail.  You can't write code that attempts to find any or all unexpected behavior.  That requires human intelligence or AI to discover.  Test code can only test a specific case that it's been written to verify.  It's up to you to propose those specific cases.